# Ctypes fails to resolve 'stdout' from msvcrt

Tags: python, ctypes, msvcrt

I am trying to redirect stdout from DLL. 
This question asked plenty of times, but I decided to go through this article: [redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/)

The problem is that when I am running this line:

```
c_stdout = ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc, 'stdout')
```

I get

> ValueError: symbol 'stdout' not found

I am initializing libc unlike the method mentioned in the article since it does not work:

```
libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)
```

So I am doing

```
libc = ctypes.CDLL('msvcrt')
```

instead, but then again it does not resolve "stdout" which seems essential to the case.
Thanks.
Any help redirecting output from the dll will be also great.

Comment: Might be an *XY Problem*. Describe what you're trying to achieve, and what's not working.

Comment: `stdout` is a macro (#define) in the CRT headers, not a global variable.

Comment: Mark Tolonen: some DLL suppose to include it. do you know which? otherwise i t wouldnt have worked...